# 'Disconnected from Omni-Channel. Log in again to receive work' happening to one user only

Tags: omnichannel, chat, embedded-services

I recently implemented Embedded web chat on our website. We have three Chat license users who were able to use Omni Channel successfully for the last week. Starting on Sunday, one user is receiving the

> Disconnected from Omni-Channel. Log in again to receive work

error message whenever she attempts to log in.

There have been no changes to our chat button or presence configurations. The other two users are still able to log in and take chats without issue. Any idea what could be causing this problem for only one user?

Comment: Does the resolution section in [Omni-Channel User receives connection error 'Disconnected from Omni-Channel. Log in again to receive work'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000315768&type=1) address your query?